# If I delete my personal Facebook account, will I also lose access to Account Kit for the app I develop?

Tags: facebook, account-kit

I have a web app and I use Facebook's Account Kit for authentication. If I delete my personal Facebook account, what happens to my Facebook developer account? Will Account Kit's API still work?

Comment: most likely not. just try it ;) - you can deactivate your account anyway, without completely deleting it.

Comment: You are only allowed to have one Facebook account. You need a Facebook account to have a Facebook app which is required to use Facebook Account Kit. So yes your app will most likely get disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your AccountKit setup is tied to one app that you have already set up and should be able to see in your [Developer Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

It is a requirement for each app to have at least one valid Administrator. You should be able to delete your account, as long as you made sure to add someone else as an Administrator (and confirm that they accepted the request).